# Read text from image file in Java

Tags: java, ocr

What is the best open source Java library that I can use to extract text from an image (JPEG, PNG) files?

Comment: you mean OCR? or reading the image info like EXIF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/) and [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), but I'm not sure about how their current releases stack up -- what about trying both on some typical inputs you need to deal with, and choose by this trial?