# how can I convert pdf file to word file using Java

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word

How can I convert a pdf file to word file using Java?

And, is it as easy as it looks like?

Comment: google it and you will find your answer. You should also use the search engine of stackoverflow...

Comment: You can use aphace poi. http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Where does it look easy?

Comment: @Holger, I did, but I need some answers.

Comment: Post your tried code. Then i will show the answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, It reminds me of manipulating files in java, by doing just integrate api conserne

Comment: @Ronny, but apache poi, can't convert a PDF file, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [PDFBOX](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

```
public class PDFTextReader
{
   static String pdftoText(String fileName) {
        PDFParser parser;
        String parsedText = null;
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        COSDocument cosDoc = null;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            System.err.println("File " + fileName + " does not exist.");
            return null;
        }
        try {
            parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        try {
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err
                    .println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document."
                            + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (cosDoc != null)
                    cosDoc.close();
                if (pdDoc != null)
                    pdDoc.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return parsedText;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

         try {

            String content = pdftoText(PDF_FILE_PATH);

            File file = new File("/sample/filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Download the jar : http://mirror.nexcess.net/apache/pdfbox/1.8.2/pdfbox-1.8.2.jar

Comment: thank you very much, but what about images and mathematical characters please? Will I need to convert this to Word file directly ?

Comment: Your PDF having images and mathematical characters

Comment: Yes, but converting it to a text file, it can't resolve this issue.

Comment: Because, it only read text from the PDF. But image is possible only by OCR.

Comment: Use this to read text from images http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: the problem is that I'm trying to encode a console application for fun to convert my pdf file, it contains images, special characters, italics, etc.. Do you know another library  to achieve this please? Otherwise thank you very much for the code and the library that you have provided me, they help me later I think ;)

Comment: Its only done through by OCR.

Comment: Can I integrate it into the code ?

Comment: Take a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442608/read-text-from-image-file-in-java

Comment: I don't find any examples about it :/

Comment: If you need the exact answer, you simply modify the question. Because you asked how to read the pdf. so every one thing that way. they dont know what do you want.

Comment: Oh, because OCR is too difficult to do the process and it takes long time to extract the image content. I use the JPedal jar http://www.idrsolutions.com/demo-landing-page/ simply run the jar through your console

Comment: You're right, but can you help me please to find some examples about this extract. I found [this](http://files.idrsolutions.com/samplecode/org/jpedal/examples/images/ExtractImages.java.html) but it wouldn't work for me, Eclipse can't find this package **com.sun.media.jai**

Comment: Its a 3rd party jar. You can download the com.sun.media jar http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsunjaicodecjar.htm

Comment: You are always welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I have looked deeply into this matter and I found that for proper results, you need cannot avoid using MS Word. Even funded projects such as LibreOffice struggle with the proper conversion as the Word format is rather complex and changes over the versions. Only MS Word keeps track of this.

For this reason, I implemented [documents4j](http://documents4j.com) what delegates conversions to MS Word using a Java API. Furthermore, it allows you to move the conversions to a different machine which you can contact using a REST API. You find detailed information [on its GitHub page](https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j).

Comment: `The type com.documents4j.job.AbstractConverterBuilder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files ` and that type does not exist in the javadoc reference

Comment: Seems like your class path is incomplete. The javadoc only contains the official API classes.