# I need to convert PDDocument to File Object

Tags: java, casting, pdfbox

I am trying to split a pdf document through `org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter` and need to perform certain file operations on this single page `PDDocument`,

How can I convert `PDDocument` to File Object in java?

Comment: check the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986305/how-can-i-convert-pdf-file-to-word-file-using-java

Comment: Have you thought about saving it into a file with the `save()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. I am using 1.8.16

```
    try {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));


        // do what ever you want
        document.save(newfilename);



    } catch (IOException | BadSecurityHandlerException | CryptographyException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(document != null )
            try {
                document.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return tmpFile != null ? tmpFile.getAbsolutePath() : null;
        return tmpFilename;
    }
```

Comment: The OP indirectly has indicated that he uses a 2.x version (the `Splitter` class has been moved to the `org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf` package not before 2.0). Thus, version 1.8.16 references are not really helpful for him.

Answer (score 0):

with Apache commons

```
   InputStream is = null
    try {
     PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(filePath);
     File targetFile = new File("nameoffile.pdf");
     PDStream ps = new PDStream(document);
     is = ps.createInputStream();
     FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, targetFile);
    } catch (IOException io) {} finally {
     if (is != null)
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }
```

Comment: Your code is partly incorrect (there is no `inputStream` method in `PDStream`, and the `load()` method doesn't accept a string in 2.0.2), and it creates an empty file. And you call `inputStream()` twice, and once without closing.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thx for pointing out, seems PDDocument have a load overloaded method with file path https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load(java.lang.String).

Comment: The OP indirectly has indicated that he uses a 2.x version (the `Splitter` class has been moved to the `org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf` package not before 2.0). Thus, version 1.8.10 references are not really helpful for him.

Comment: Regardless of the version, after correcting the errors the result file will always be empty. `new PDStream(document)` means to create an empty stream, with the scratch file setings of the document in the parameter. This answer should be deleted.