# How to read images using Java API?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, tiff

I have been using a piece of Software that works as a Reading Scanner. Basically it retrieves text from images. Is there any API for Java that would enable programmatically recognize text contained in images, in particular `.tiff` to regular text? Or is there any Java class that would help ... I do not know how to start

Comment: have a look at this: https://github.com/axet/lookup and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in previous post.

Read

1. [Java OCR implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)
2. [Turn Image into Text - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419577/turn-image-into-text-java)
3. [Read text from image file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442608/read-text-from-image-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is called Optical Character Recognition or OCR. The first Google result for "Java OCR"  looks promising: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr